# How can an user have a lot of upvotes on many questions but still have low reputation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, help-center

How does a person having 137 upvotes on a question have only 198 reputation?
See the profile of [Marco.W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89818/marco-w) on stackoverflow.com.

I see some statistics like below, but I am unable to get it exactly.

```
all time        by type     
--------------  ---------------
820 up          137 question    
131 down        814 answer
```

Comment: It's coincidental that his top question has 137 votes and he has also cast 137 votes on questions. I can see how that can be confusing... (Those statistics are the votes cast *by* the user. Not the votes the user has *received*.)

Comment: In addition to bounties, as discussed in the answers, the rep cap often comes into play here when comparing amounts of upvotes with actual rep received.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock and Chichiray for editing and teaching me to write proper sentence.

Answer (score 9):

That person has offered 5050 rep away in bounties.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/89818/marco-w?tab=bounties&sort=offered

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The votes that are shown on the profile page are the total votes cast ***by*** the user not the total votes cast ***for*** the user.

[image]

So they voted 137 times for questions and 814 times on answers.  These votes (unless they are downvotes) will not change their total reputation.

Even though the user has a post that has 137 upvotes, the main reason the users rep is so low is they also have offered [79 bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89818/marco-w?tab=bounties&sort=offered) that gave away their rep.

Comment: that user also has a question that has a score of 137  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener

Comment: @SamIam Right, but the stats that they displayed in the OP were from the profile page. Not only that, the user did give away 5k of rep in bounties which I included in my answer.

Comment: the 137 score question **is** evedient from the profile page

Comment: @SamIam I am not disputing the 137 upvotes on the one question, I am saying that the stats that were posted in this OP were showing the votes cast not the up/down votes on the users questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a reputation cap at 200 rep/day.
If the user were to get all 137 upvotes in one day, he would only get **200** rep, **not** 10 * 137 = 1370.

The above is what would happen in the extreme case, that is if he got all the votes in one day.

If he were to get all the votes in 2 days, he would be affected by the daily rep cap twice and have 200 * 2 = **400** rep from that question.

If he got them over 3 days he would have 600, etc...

It also gets a little bit more complicated though, as "accepts" are not affected by the cap. Since his was the accepted answer, he will still get the 15 rep for the accept regardless of whether or not he has already hit the cap, bringing his 3 day total to:
215 + 200 + 200 = 615. Provided his answer was accepted on the first day.

[See the reputation faq for more info about rep.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/210436)

Comment: and if he getting all these upvotes gradually then?

Comment: @diEcho I have updated my answer to give a better description of what happens in regards to the cap.

Comment: Explanation are quite complicated..anyways Thanks for this. One day i will underdstand what u have said..

Comment: Reputation is a complicated subject. [Take a look here for more depth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).